# BIDS 2005 SSIS Multiple XML files with different names to import to DB

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, bids

I have created an SSIS package that has a Foreach Loop container with a Data Flow Task inside it that points to a Data Flow constructed of an XML Source and an OLE DB Destination. When the XML Source is created it requires that I point to an existing XML file as my 'starter' file. However, I don't want this same file to be imported over and over again, I want to be able to add and remove files from the folder location without having to change the package each time. Creating an empty XML file isn't the answer because the DB throws an error that the values it's expecting violate column restraints. I do not know how many XML files will be generated at any given time, it could 1 it could 100.

Here's the overall view of what I want to achieve:

```
  1) User generates one or more XML files in a specific folder location:
        Example: MyFile12456.xml
                 MyFile298654.xml
                 MyFile33265.xml
  2) User executes SSIS package:
       a) Each xml file is read into the database
       b) After import each xml file is moved to another folder 
          -- files are being moved to avoid duplication 
             of import and to be archived
```

How do I fix the [XML Source].[XMLData] to reference a file that does not have to be changed but avoid import duplication?

Is it possible to set the reference and then ask it to ignore that file?

Comment: Please look at this [example](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the page, it does seem like fairly complete information but it does appear that I have to use a flat file format to achieve what I want, that using XML does not work or I have yet to find an example that works.

Comment: One thing about the example, I had to leave my varSourcePath blank because it was reading the path already established in the Flat File Connection.